# Serial asynchronous I/O in Windows 7/64

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, asynchronous, serial-port

I have a multi-threaded Windows program which is doing serial port asynchronous I/O through "raw" Win API calls. It is working perfectly fine on any Windows version except Windows 7/64.

The problem is that the program can find and setup the COM port just fine, but it cannot send nor receive any data. No matter if I compile the binary in Win XP or 7, I cannot send/receive on Win 7/64. Compatibility mode, run as admin etc does not help.

I have managed to narrow down the problem to the FileIOCompletionRoutine callback. Every time it is called, dwErrorCode is always 0, dwNumberOfBytesTransfered is always 0. GetOverlappedResult() from inside the function always return TRUE (everything ok). It seems to set the lpNumberOfBytesTransferred correctly. But the lpOverlapped parameter is corrupt, it is a garbage pointer pointing at garbage values.

I can see that it is corrupt by either checking in the debugger what address the correct OVERLAPPED struct is allocated at, or by setting a temp. global variable to point at it.

My question is: why does this happen, and why does it only happen on Windows 7/64? Is there some issue with calling convention that I am not aware of? Or is the overlapped struct treated differently somehow?

---

Posting relevant parts of the code below:

```
class ThreadedComport : public Comport
{
  private:

    typedef struct
    {
      OVERLAPPED       overlapped;
      ThreadedComport* caller;                   /* add user data to struct */
    } OVERLAPPED_overlap;

    OVERLAPPED_overlap _send_overlapped;
    OVERLAPPED_overlap _rec_overlapped;

  ...

static void WINAPI  _send_callback     (DWORD dwErrorCode,
                                        DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
                                        LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped);
static void WINAPI  _receive_callback  (DWORD dwErrorCode,
                                        DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
                                        LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped);

  ...
};
```

Open/close is done in a base class that has no multi-threading nor asynchronous I/O implemented:

```
void Comport::open (void)
{
  char          port[20];
  DCB           dcbCommPort;
  COMMTIMEOUTS  ctmo_new      = {0};

  if(_is_open)
  {
    close();
  }

  sprintf(port, "\\\\.\\COM%d", TEXT(_port_number));

  _hcom = CreateFile(port,
                     GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                     0,
                     0,
                     OPEN_EXISTING,
                     0,
                     0);

  if(_hcom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
   // error handling
  }

  GetCommTimeouts(_hcom, &_ctmo_old);
  ctmo_new.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant    = 10;
  ctmo_new.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier  = 0;
  ctmo_new.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
  ctmo_new.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant   = 0;

  if(SetCommTimeouts(_hcom, &ctmo_new) == FALSE)
  {
    // error handling
  }

  dcbCommPort.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);
  if(GetCommState(_hcom, &(DCB)dcbCommPort) == FALSE)
  {
    // error handling
  }

  // setup DCB, this seems to work fine

  dcbCommPort.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);
  dcbCommPort.BaudRate = baudrate_int;

  if(_parity == PAR_NONE)
  {
    dcbCommPort.fParity = 0;                     /* disable parity */
  }
  else
  {
    dcbCommPort.fParity = 1;                     /* enable parity */
  }
  dcbCommPort.Parity  = (uint8)_parity;
  dcbCommPort.ByteSize = _databits;
  dcbCommPort.StopBits = _stopbits;

  SetCommState(_hcom, &(DCB)dcbCommPort);
}


void Comport::close (void)
{
  if(_hcom != NULL)
  {
    SetCommTimeouts(_hcom, &_ctmo_old);
    CloseHandle(_hcom);
    _hcom = NULL;
  }
  _is_open = false;
}
```

The whole multi-threading and event handling mechanism is rather complex, relevant parts are:

Send

```
result = WriteFileEx (_hcom,              // handle to output file
                      (void*)_write_data, // pointer to input buffer
                      send_buf_size,      // number of bytes to write
                      (LPOVERLAPPED)&_send_overlapped, // pointer to async. i/o data
                      (LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE )&_send_callback);
```

Receive

```
  result = ReadFileEx (_hcom,                  // handle to output file
                       (void*)_read_data,      // pointer to input buffer
                       _MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH,    // number of bytes to read
                       (OVERLAPPED*)&_rec_overlapped, // pointer to async. i/o data
                       (LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE )&_receive_callback);
```

Callback functions

```
void WINAPI ThreadedComport::_send_callback (DWORD dwErrorCode,
                                             DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
                                             LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
{
  ThreadedComport* _this = ((OVERLAPPED_overlap*)lpOverlapped)->caller;

  if(dwErrorCode == 0)                           // no errors
  {
    if(dwNumberOfBytesTransfered > 0)
    {
      _this->_data_sent = dwNumberOfBytesTransfered;
    }
  }

  SetEvent(lpOverlapped->hEvent);
}


void WINAPI ThreadedComport::_receive_callback (DWORD dwErrorCode,
                                                DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
                                                LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
{
  if(dwErrorCode == 0)                           // no errors
  {
    if(dwNumberOfBytesTransfered > 0)
    {
      ThreadedComport* _this = ((OVERLAPPED_overlap*)lpOverlapped)->caller;
      _this->_bytes_read = dwNumberOfBytesTransfered;
    }
  }

  SetEvent(lpOverlapped->hEvent);
}
```

**EDIT**

Updated: I have spent most of the day on the theory that the OVERLAPPED variable went out of scope before the callback is executed. I have verified that this never happens and I have even tried to declare the OVERLAPPED struct as static, same problem remains. If the OVERLAPPED struct had gone out of scope, I would expect the callback to point at the memory location where the struct was previously allocated, but it doesn't, it points somewhere else, at an entirely unfamiliar memory location. Why it does that, I have no idea.

Maybe Windows 7/64 makes an internal hardcopy of the OVERLAPPED struct? I can see how that would cause this behavior, since I am relying on additional parameters sneaked in at the end of the struct (which seems like a hack to me, but apparently I got that "hack" from official MSDN examples).

I have also tried to change calling convention but this doesn't work at all, if I change it then the program crashes. (The standard calling convention causes it to crash, whatever standard is, cdecl? __fastcall also causes a crash.) The calling conventions that work are __stdcall, WINAPI and CALLBACK. I think these are all same names for __stdcall and I read somewhere that Win 64 ignores that calling convention anyhow.

It would seem that the callback is executed because of some "spurious disturbance" in Win 7/64 generating false callback calls with corrupt or irrelevant parameters.

Multi-thread race conditions is another theory, but in the scenario I am running to reproduce the bug, there is only one thread, and I can confirm that the thread calling ReadFileEx is the same one that is executing the callback.

Comment: Start by getting rid of the awful casts in the Read/WriteFileEx() calls.  That accomplishes nothing but stopping the compiler from telling you that you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant This code works partially with libraries written for embedded system, that use uint8 for strings. The API function expects a plain `char` which has implementation-defined signedness. Thus the cast removes completely irrelevant warnings of casting between uint8 and char. Since there exist no negative index symbol tables anywhere in the universe, the cast is perfectly safe on any system.

Comment: Please stop voting to close posts just because the topic is too advanced. If there is a bug in Windows 7/64 that causes asynchronous I/O to misbehave, the question is not too localized. If the bug is in my code, then it might indeed be quite localized. Before we know the source of the bug, it is too early to tell.

Comment: @Lundin: The close vote was for "too localized" and most "bugs" come under this category. I don't agree in this case, but many are down to typos or stupid mistakes.

Comment: @Deanna It just annoys me that there are hundreds of users/trolls actively trying to scare away on-topic questions from this site. The on-going arrogant trend seems to be vote-to-close on any topic they haven't got clue about.

Comment: I certainly would not class overlapped I/O as 'too localized' - many Windows servers etc. use it.  I use it for servers and COM port I/O.  It's not even that advanced - it's an async callback mechanism.  I did see the close votes - coundn't understand them at all:(

Comment: Maybe it's penguin-panic: not a bash script, so must be too advanced:)

Comment: Just so we're sure - this is a 32-bit app running on W7-64, right?

Comment: Hmm... I wonder how big the hEvent handle is on 64, or if there are any 64-bit alignment requirments?  Maybe the 'this' is getting overwritten?  Guessin' now:(   I don't use any extensions to the overlapped struct in my code - I put the buffer context object in the hEvent field. IF you want/need to do event signaling, maybe you cold try my approach but create an event in the context object?

Comment: Do you have a single instance of `ThreadedComport` for the life of your app?  Or are you creating and destroying them?

Comment: @arx I am currently investigating the theories of object going out of scope and stack overflow since they seem to be the most likely culprits, even though I don't see how such issues would arise just because of 64. The ThreadedComport is created and destroyed multiple times in the app, they are created whenever the user wants to send/receive anything, and then they are destroyed to free memory and give up the port itself, in case there are other applications on the computer that want to access the port while mine is running.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes it is a 32-bit app, either compiled in Win XP or Win 7/64. Same issue no matter where the binary is created.

Comment: The classic reason for getting a bogus overlapped pointer is because an I/O has completed after you've destroyed your object.  It's possible that, say, cancelled I/Os take longer to complete on 64-bit windows.  [Lots of details here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/02/10123392.aspx).

Comment: @arx In this case I'm rather certain that the object is not out of scope: since everything resides in a single class, I can just set a breakpoint in the constructor, the destructor and the callback function. If the destructor would be called before the callback, then I would have an obvious bug there. But that never happens. I have also tried to declare the OVERLAPPED structs as static, but same problem remains. The parameters of the callback function are corrupted.

Comment: Please try to simplify your code so we can easily try it.  Read sscce.org.  Also, try rebooting your computer.

Comment: Make sure you check the error/return value for every winapi function you call to make sure they succeeded.

Comment: To simplify:  first put all code in one file.  Then merge the two classes.  Then get rid of the class.  Then remove any unimportant lines.

Comment: Yeah - this is odd.  I can't really see much wrong with the OP code.  The tx/rx OVL are class members, there is only one tx/rx issued at a time.  No ctor shown but I guess the event is created OK and something waits on it after issuing the R/W 'Ex' calls.  I can't say that I'm happy with the idea of continually creating/destroying this class. If the correct peer is plugged in, there's probably not much point in other apps trying to comunicate with it.  Still, that should not stuff the OP code and I still got nothin' :(

Comment: @MartinJames Actually my previous comment seems to be incorrect. The class and the corresponding thread isn't created over and over; there's an open/close function used each time communication is initiated/done. So it doesn't really go out of scope as often as I first thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem, it turned out to be annoyingly simple.

In CreateFile(), I did not specify FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED. For reasons unknown, this was not necessary on 32-bit Windows. But if you forget it on 64-bit Windows, it will apparently still generate callbacks with the FileIOCompletionRoutine, but they have corrupted parameters.

I haven't found any documentation of this change of behavior anywhere; perhaps it was just an internal bug fix in Windows, since the older documentation also specifies that you must have FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED set.

As for my specific case, the bug appeared because I had a base class that assumed synchronous I/O, which has then been inherited by a class using asynchronous I/O.

Comment: Heh - never looked at that 'cos I would have expected it to not work at all on any OS without the overlapped flag on the open. How wierd is that :)

Comment: `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` absolute independ from 32/64 bit

Comment: @RbMm This bug was about what will happen when using the flags incorrectly. If you didn't set it prior to Win 7/64 but used overlapped I/O still, it worked. But if you did the same bug on 64, the program crashed.

Comment: absolute sure that no. task here not in this. if you use this flag in `CreateFile` io will be asynchronous. if not set - no. this not depend from 32/64 bit or os version. but you use apc callbacks - which will be called if operation complete success. even for synchronous io. i sure that problem in your code was in something else

Comment: @RbMm Nope, this was it. The only change I did was the one in the answer and then the program stopped crashing.

Comment: @Lundin - `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` effects independent from windows versionsand 32/64. and if you want asynchronous io - it must set it (in call `CreateFile`) for both 32 and 64. effect here some another - wow64 processes have another pointer size and iosb size. system special [mark](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Io/iomgr/read.c#L163) wow64 apc params, but only in case no `FO_SYNCHRONOUS_IO` on file (`FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` is used). if you not use `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` - system not mark you apc such and then incorrect process in `IopCompleteRequest`

Comment: you can more easy and stable reproduce it - if simply open any disk file form wow64 process and then do read with apc (`ReadFileEx` or `NtReadFile`) after read call say `SleepEx(INFINITE,TRUE)` - and compare pointers to iosb(overlapped) passed to call and in callback. this related to mangle (`PsWrapApcWow64Thread`) apc params which is doing for wow64 processes (but in some place only for asynchronous files, in some place - always)

Comment: you can test this - https://pastebin.com/HfRZNFe1 or this - https://pastebin.com/0W8GbhSk from wow64 process for view that is second case - wrong iosb(overlapped) pointer passed